# How to create additional rows for each day between two dates in SAS?

Tags: loops, date, sas, transform

I'm looking for the SAS code to create "new" rows for each days between two dates. 
E.g. I have the original dataset containing:

```
Num. StartDate EndDate  Tag
5      13JUN2017 25NOV2017  1
6      1JAN2017 4MAR2017   5 
...
```

etc. and I need to transpose this dataset with

```
Num. Day           TAG
5      13JUN2017     1
5      14JUN2017     1
... 
5      25NOV2017     1
6      1JAN2017      5
...
6      4MAR2017      5
...
```

Can anyone help? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Already found it!

Comment: Place that discovery into an answer below, and accept it. Then we won't navigate into this question expecting someone needs help still. Please do this. Others looking for it may also thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **do while**

```
data have;
input num startdate enddate tag;
informat startdate date9. enddate date9.;
format startdate date9. enddate date9.;
cards;
5 13jun2017 25nov2017 1
6 01jan2017 04mar2017 5
;
run;

data want; 
set have;
format next_due_date date9.;
next_due_date = startdate;
do while (enddate > next_due_date);
next_due_date = intnx("day",next_due_date,1);   
output;
end;
run;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Since SAS stores dates as integers you can just use a simple `do next_due_date=startdate to enddate;` loop instead.  But the do while loop is useful if you wanted to increment by date intervals other than `day`.

Comment: @tom if I want to increment by date intervals other than day, even then I could use "do" by simply giving "by" statement. "do & do while" both can be used for both the queries(increment by day as well as time interval). Isn't it?

Comment: @pinegulf Happy to help!!