# Creating a list of unique dates in between date entries for multiple subjects in SAS?

Tags: date, sas

I have a list of subjects with multiple stop dates in the following format:

`Subjid    startdate    stopdate`

```
1    101    07MAR2014    07MAR2014
2    105    30MAR2017    03APR2017
3    105    03APR2017    09APR2017
```

I want the output to be:

```
1    101   07MAR2014
2    105   30MAR2017
3    105   31MAR2017
4    105   01APR2017
5    105   02APR2017
6    105   03APR2017
7    105   04APR2017
8    105   05APR2017
9    105   06APR2017
...
```

And so on.

Keeping in mind that there's multiple date entries for each subject ID, and many of the dates overlap, is it possible to get a list of unique days in chronological order based on my original table?

Some similar questions like this have been partially answered ([How to create additional rows for each day between two dates in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428867/how-to-create-additional-rows-for-each-day-between-two-dates-in-sas), for example), but I have been unable to get the code to work and don't know if it will work for multiple subjects with overlapping entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just generate all of the dates and then eliminate the duplicates. If you use a view to generate the dates then you only need to process the source data once.

```
data have;
  input Subjid $ (startdate stopdate) (:date.);
  format startdate stopdate date9.;
cards;
101    07MAR2014    07MAR2014
105    30MAR2017    03APR2017
105    03APR2017    09APR2017
;

data tall / view=tall;
  set have;
  do date=startdate to stopdate;
    output;
  end;
  format date date9.;
  drop startdate stopdate;
run;

proc sort data=tall out=want nodupkey;
  by subjid date;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Track the min `startdate` and max `stopdate` for each id (group), and also **flag** every `date` in each date range using a *key indexed* temporary array.  SAS date values are integers and can be used as an array *index*.  At the end of the group `output` each flagged `date`.

Example:

Use DOW loop to process one group within each implicit loop iteration.  Easiest explanation of DOW loop is that the `SET` and `BY` statement is inside the loop and terminates at last row of by group.

```
data want(keep=id date);
  _min = 1e9;
  _max = -1e9;

  * dow loop;

  array dates (0:100000) _temporary_;

  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;

    do date = startdate to stopdate;
      dates(date) = 1;
    end;

    _min = min (_min, startdate);
    _max = max (_max, stopdate);
  end;

  * output loop;

  do date = _min to _max;
    if dates(date) then output;
  end;

  call missing(of dates(*));

  format date date9.;
run;
```